# How to allocate a struct dynamically in C to avoid a segmentation fault?

Tags: c

I'm having a problem to allocate a structure dynamically.
I'm making a program that works as a contact book, but I'm getting the
following error: Segmentation fault (core dumped).

The structure declaration, following the functions to add a contact
and print all contacts:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct contact{
    int number;
    char name[80];
}contact;

void addContact(contact **contacts, int position){
    int aux=position;
    printf("Enter the name: ");
    setbuf(stdin, 0);
    fgets(contacts[position]->name,80,stdin);
    

    printf("Enter the telephone number: ");
    scanf("%d",&contacts[position]->number);
    return;
}

void printAllContacts(contact **contacts, int size){
    for(int i;i<size;i++){
        printf("Contact %d:\n",i);
        printf("Name: %s\n",contacts[i]->name);
        printf("Telephone number: %d \n",contacts[i]->number);
    }
}


// Main function:

int main(){
    int size;
    printf("Enter the list size: ");
    scanf("%d",&size);

    contact *contacts= (contact*)malloc(sizeof(contact)*size);
    int counter=0;
    int x;

    do{
        printf("------------MENU-----------\n");
        printf("1-Add contact\n");
        printf("2-Print contacts list\n");
        printf("0-Exit\n");
        printf("----------------------------\n");
        printf("Enter an option: ");
        scanf("%d",&x);

        switch (x){
            case 1:
                addContact(&contacts,counter);
                counter++;
                break;
            case 2:
                printAllContacts(&contacts,counter);
                break;
            case 0:
                break;        
        }
    }while(x!=0);


    return 0;

}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Run your program in a debugger (gdb) to see where it crashes.

Comment: `i` is not initialized in printAllContacts().

Comment: It's much more helpful to supply a [mre] instead of snippets (which in this case is one program).  For an interactive program you should tell us how to reproduce the crash, or even better hard-code a failing test case.

Comment: You have a core dump.  It is extremely useful to learn how to get information from it.

Comment: You can pass the address of the pointer, but you need to dereference before you index. E.g. in `addContact(contact **contacts, ...)` you can do `fgets((*contacts)[position].name,80,stdin);` and `scanf("%d",&(*contacts)[position].number);`. This isn't to say that you **"should"** do it this way, but if you answer the question -- what is my pointer -- you can make it work just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic problem is that you're allocating an array of `struct contact` objects, but your `addContact` and `printAllContacts` expect an array of pointers to `struct contact`.  You need to choose one or the other.

The easiest fix is probably to change the functions -- change the argument type to `contact *` instead of `contact **`, remove the `&` at the call site in main, and change the `->` to `.` in the functions where needed.

Comment: I thought it was necessary to pass the struct by reference to change the value in the function.  The aswer helped a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

1. Pass in a pointer (`contacts *`) instead of pointer to pointer (`contacts **`) to `addContact()` & `printAllContacts()`.  Updated caller, and partially updated called code which already assumed it was operating on an array.
2. Initialize `i` in `printAllContacts()`.
3. Removed the unnecessary cast of `malloc()` return value.
4. Removed the name of the struct as you use only use the typedef.
5. Introduced a NAME_LEN macro instead of the magic `80` value.
6. Minor reformatting for readability & consistency.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NAME_LEN 80

typedef struct {
    int number;
    char name[NAME_LEN];
} contact;

void addContact(contact *contacts, int position) {
    printf("Enter the name: ");
    setbuf(stdin, 0);
    fgets(contacts[position].name, NAME_LEN, stdin);

    printf("Enter the telephone number: ");
    scanf("%d", &contacts[position].number);
    return;
}

void printAllContacts(contact *contacts, int size) {
    for(int i=0; i<size;i++) {
        printf("Contact %d:\n", i);
        printf("Name: %s\n", contacts[i].name);
        printf("Telephone number: %d\n", contacts[i].number);
    }
}

int main() {
    int size;
    printf("Enter the list size: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    contact *contacts = malloc(sizeof(contact)*size);
    int counter=0;
    int x;
    do {
        printf("------------MENU-----------\n");
        printf("1-Add contact\n");
        printf("2-Print contacts list\n");
        printf("0-Exit\n");
        printf("----------------------------\n");
        printf("Enter an option: ");
        scanf("%d", &x);

        switch (x) {
            case 1:
                addContact(contacts, counter++);
                break;
            case 2:
                printAllContacts(contacts, counter);
                break;
            case 0:
                break;
        }
    } while(x!=0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Worth the old note on [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: Yeah, just figured I would leave the change minimal.  Fixed.

Comment: No harm, the real issue is the general use of the cast that will mask compiler type warnings. So long as it is a cast to a correct pointer type, then there is no harm, but avoiding the cast ensures none of those issues sneak in.

Answer (score 0):

I would add additional structure holding all the contacts and also keeping the number of contacts stored. You do not need to know the size of the list - it will grow with any added contact.

When you test the idea I would advise you to not use user input functions, only fixed data. It makes debugging and testing faster and easier. Especially function which adds data should not communicate with the external world. Caller is the correct place to do it

Also use function return values to return result or status codes. You tend to use `void` everywhere - it is not a good idea.

```
typedef struct contact{
    unsigned number;
    char name[80];
}contact;

typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    contact contacts[];
}constactList;

constactList *addContact(constactList *list, const char *name, const unsigned number)
{
    size_t newsize = list ? list -> size + 1 : 1;
    list = realloc(list, sizeof(*list) + sizeof(list -> contacts[0]) * newsize);
    if(list)
    {
        strncpy(list -> contacts[list -> size].name, name, sizeof(list -> contacts[0].name));
        list -> contacts[list -> size].name[sizeof(list -> contacts[0].name) - 1] = 0;  
        list -> contacts[list -> size].number = number;
        list -> size = newsize;
    }
    return list;
}

void printContacts(const constactList *list)
{
    if(list)
    {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < list -> size; i++) printf("[%3zu] %s, %u\n", i, list -> contacts[i].name, list -> contacts[i].number);
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    constactList *list = NULL;

    list = addContact(list, "James Bond", 7);
    if(!list) {/* error handling*/}
    list = addContact(list, "Mata Hari", 99);
    if(!list) {/* error handling*/}
    list = addContact(list, "Wladymir Putin", 666);
    if(!list) {/* error handling*/}
    printContacts(list);
    free(list);
}
```